# Почему не все потоки воспроизводятся в playerJS?

Tags: javascript, hls, playerjs

В наличии 50 потоков ТВ каналов они все идентичны по кодекам, но некоторые работают отлично, некоторые не воспроизводятся. В браузере network качает сегменты в консоли ошибок нет, время воспроизведения всех сегментов показывает, но само видео не воспроизводится. Сервер на Astra. В чем может быть проблема? В vlc все отлично открывает.